# How can I receive update status(data) when I request ride with UBSDKRideRequestViewController (Uber SDK)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uber-api

I have added Uber SDK in my application. I didn't request project to `Request full access`. It's on development. and I have issues that I can't find an answer (I'm using `sandbox` mode.)

Q. I need to test. If I requested and driver is already accepted. How can I know the time that he will arrive or other status e.g.`arrived` . and How can I send notification to my user in my application when driver is arrived. I see `UBSDKRideRequestViewControllerDelegate` response only error case.

this's my code.

```
UBSDKRideParametersBuilder *builder = [[UBSDKRideParametersBuilder alloc] init];
[builder setPickupToCurrentLocation];
[builder setDropoffLocation:dropoffLocation];
UBSDKRideParameters *parameters = [builder build];

NSArray<UBSDKRidesScope *> *scopes = @[UBSDKRidesScope.RideWidgets,UBSDKRidesScope.Profile,UBSDKRidesScope.Request];

UBSDKLoginManager *loginManager = [[UBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
UBSDKRideRequestViewController *vc = [[UBSDKRideRequestViewController alloc] initWithRideParameters:parameters loginManager:loginManager];
vc.title = @"Uber";
vc.delegate = self;
```

please advice thanks.

Comment: They've coded a sdk for us [link](https://github.com/uber/rides-ios-sdk). I think, You'll get all you need there..

Comment: @AnkitNeoGHz Thanks for answer me. I already looked. but there's not have what I want. :D

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the Ride Request Widget does not provide you notifications for changes in trip status. You can, however, get the status of the current trip by using a `RidesClient` and calling `fetchCurrentRide` which will give you details about the current trip. In order to access trips from the widget on this endpoint, however, you will need the `all_trips` scope. This will require you to handle login separately from the  RideRequestViewController. You can use the LoginButton or LoginManager to request the `AllTrips` and `RideWidgets` RidesScopes

In terms of testing, you can update the status of a sandbox trip by making a PUT request to the `/v1/sandbox/requests/{request_id}` endpoint with a JSON body in the form `{"status": "accepted"}` (replacing the status you want to see). This status change would then be reflected in your app. You can find more information on the sandbox on the [Uber Developer Site](https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/sandbox)

Comment: How can I add more scopes in `UBSDKRideRequestViewController` ?

Comment: Now, I know how to get request_id. I can get it in `fetchCurrentRide` method. but my problem is it always response an error. error code is "unauthorised", error title is "Requires at least one scope. Available scopes:". I think this because my scopes is not allow. Isn't it?.

Comment: Method `fetchCurrentRide` is always response error code is `unauthorised `

Comment: That's right, in order to see a request from the ride widget, you will need to request the `all_trips` scope. Since this is a privileged scope, you will have to log your users in via Single Sign On or Authorization Code Grant, so you won't be able to add the scopes to the RideRequestViewController. I've updated my answer to reflect this

Comment: @JohnBrophy Hey there, John.. I'm kinda confused. I'm implementing the solution you mentioned just to get the request_id for the sandbox api... In production I'd never need this AllTrips scope (as the Uber ride would progress itself by its own). As my app doesn't have this scope authorized yet (and according to the Uber revision team, I needed to show screencasts for their approval) is this really the best approach for testing the request through UBSDKRideRequestViewController? I thought this would come (the id at least) through a delegate

Comment: hi @JohnBrophy kindly take a look at my problem. Sorry for getting your attention here. Here's the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42387082/uber-sdk-for-ios-get-real-time-ride-request-status-made-via-deep-link