# Uber SDK for iOS - get real time ride request status made via deep link

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uber-api

I'm having some trouble finding a way to do this. I got an app that uses Uber SDK for iOS. I was able to add the "RideRequestButton" with "Ride there with Uber" text to do a deeplink to the Uber app. Also, I'm done requesting the token using SSO and fetch the token with Request scope. Now the problem is... I'm not sure how to fetch the status of the current ride request made via the deeplink. Is this possible?

Thanks!

---

I tried following an algorithm mentioned in one of the thread which is to use the RidesClient to fetch the current ride then get the current ride detail after obtaining the ride requestID. Here's a glimpse of my code:

```
func refreshRideRequestStatus () {
    var requestID: String = ""
    self.ridesClient.fetchCurrentRide({
        ride, response in
        if (ride != nil) {
            print ("[refreshRideRequestStatus] ride:", ride ?? "no active ride")
            requestID = (ride?.requestID)!
        }
        else {
            print ("[refreshRideRequestStatus] ride: no active ride")
            print ("[refreshRideRequestStatus] response: ", response.response ?? "no response")
        }
    })

    if (requestID.isEmpty) {
        print ("[refreshRideRequestStatus] no active request")
    }
    else {
        print ("[refreshRideRequestStatus] requestID: ", requestID)
        self.ridesClient.fetchRideDetails(requestID, completion: {
            ride, response in
            self.isTorchUberFlashable = false
            if (response.statusCode == 200) {
                let status:Int = (ride?.status)!.rawValue
                print("refreshRideRequestStatus] status:", status)
                switch (status) {
                case 1: 
                    print("[refreshRideRequestStatus] accepted")
                case 2:
                    print("[refreshRideRequestStatus] arriving")
                case 3:
                    print("[refreshRideRequestStatus] completed")
                case 4:
                    print("[refreshRideRequestStatus] driverCanceled")
                case 5:
                    print("[refreshRideRequestStatus] inProgress")
                case 6:
                    print("[refreshRideRequestStatus] noDriversAvailable")
                case 7:
                    print("[refreshRideRequestStatus] processing")
                case 8:
                    print("[refreshRideRequestStatus] ridersCanceled")
                case 9:
                    print("[refreshRideRequestStatus] unknown")
                default:break
                }
            }
            else {
                print("[refreshRideRequestStatus] error: ", response.response ?? "no data request found")
            }
        })

    }
}
```

The function above is going to be called every time my app is set to foreground or became active.

Sorry but another question would be.
How will I know if this will work and is there a way to test this by requesting a real ride and complete a whole transaction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the `request` scope, you are only able to look at the status of rides that are initiated using your auth token. So if the user is deeplinking into the app and then requesting a ride from there, you will not have access to that information.

In order to get this information, you would be required to get authorized for the `all_trips` scope.

Comment: thanks @JohnBrophy!... After changing the scope request to all_trips. Is my second question doable? "How will I know if this will work and is there a way to test this by requesting a real ride and complete a whole transaction?"

Comment: You can use the sandbox to test a trip and see the webhooks notify your server when a trip is active.

Comment: Hello @John Brophy and Dustin Whittle. Thanks for your help. Just one more question. I was able to make the feature that I'm working on and tested it using a simulated ride (using CURL via terminal). My client would like to try it too. I sent them the build via testflight. They said that they're able to install it but the expected functionality didn't work on the "real world ride". The app is still in Sandbox when I upload it to iTunesConnect. Is there anything that I'm missing here? Thanks again

Comment: Do you have logging information to see where this is erring? If you're not approved for the all_trips scope, you need to have your client listed in the app's admin role, otherwise the all_trips scope will not work.